# HTML Javascript function linking

Tags: javascript, html, pycharm

I am trying to send data from html to javascript, and using document.getElementById won't cut it here.

```
{% for p in pl %}
    <li>{{ p.itemName }}: {{ p.itemPrice }} $<button onclick 
    ="deletePurchase()">Remove</button>
    <input type="hidden" placeholder="_" id="pItemName" value="{{ 
    p.itemName }}">
    </li>
{%  endfor %}
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
function deletePurchase(){
    var v = document.getElementById("pItemName").value;
    console.log(v);
}
```

Essentially, I am printing a list of items from my database. I want to have
a remove button next to each which will, when clicked, call "deletePurchase()" in my javascript. Currently, for the purpose of simplicity, I want to print the item name that is next to the "Remove" button that is pressed.

Currently, the item that is printed is always the first item's name of the list, no matter which "Remove" button is pressed.

Comment: This is not JavaScript or HTML...

Comment: The piece of code is in javascript, the first script is html.

Comment: You are using a template engine. Please tag the question accordingly.

Comment: In HTML the `id` attribute values should be unique. They are not in your code.

Comment: Is that templating system being processed server-side or client-side?  What is the actual resulting HTML of that first piece of code?  JavaScript isn't terribly concerned with the code that *generates* your HTML, it's operating on the HTML itself.  You should examine what that HTML actually is.

Comment: I understand that - I am just not sure how else to go about ID'ing each item I print

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have duplicate `id` attribute values in HTML. Instead, drop those `id` attributes, and instead look for the element that follows the `button` element that was clicked.

For that you need to pass the button as argument to the function. You can use `this` for that purpose.

To get the node following another one, you can use the method `nextSibling`. Just be careful that also white space is counted as a (text) node, so you might need to call that function more than once.

The JavaScript could look like this. I use just plain HTML just for illustration:

```js
function deletePurchase(button){
    var elem = button;
    do {
        elem = elem.nextSibling;
    } while (elem && elem.nodeType !== 1);
    
    var v = elem.value;
    console.log(v);
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li>Cola: 0.80 $<button onclick="deletePurchase(this)">Remove</button>
    <input type="hidden" placeholder="_" value="Cola">
    </li>
   <li>Coffee: 1.00 $<button onclick="deletePurchase(this)">Remove</button>
    <input type="hidden" placeholder="_" value="Coffee">
    </li>
</ul>
```

#### Alternative

As you have the buttons in separate `li` elements, you can also find the `input` element via the parent of the button:

```js
function deletePurchase(button){
    var elem = button.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=hidden]');
    var v = elem.value;
    console.log(v);
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li>Cola: 0.80 $<button onclick="deletePurchase(this)">Remove</button>
    <input type="hidden" placeholder="_" value="Cola">
    </li>
   <li>Coffee: 1.00 $<button onclick="deletePurchase(this)">Remove</button>
    <input type="hidden" placeholder="_" value="Coffee">
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you, this was extremely helpful.

Comment: You're welcome ;-)